# How to get a list of the elements in a given div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, frontend

In a given id of a `<div>` I need to get a list of all the elements which are in that div.

My goal is to get a list of all elements in the given div and loop over them hide everyone except the first one.

Example:

```
<div id="RandomId">
    <img src="src_1" />
    <img src="src_2" />
    <img src="src_3" />
    .
    .
    .
    <img src="src_n" />
</div>

<script>
    function handleImages(divID) {
        const div = document.getElementById(DivID);
        if(div) {
            const Elements = // Here, I need the list;
            for (let i = 0; i < Elements.length; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    Elements[i].style = "display:block";
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: MDN's [DOM documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) is very good. For instance: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children (with a recursive function) or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll with a `*` selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Element.children` to get the list of elements inside the *div*.

Comment: Re *"the of elements"*: Do you mean *"the number of elements"*, *"the elements"*, or *"the list of elements"*? Or something else? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74653235/edit), not here in comments (********** ***without*** ********** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
const Elements = document.querySelectorAll('#RandomId > img')
```

Answer (score 1):

That's very easy to do when you're using native JavaScript. Use the following:

```html
<script>
function handleImages(divID){
    const div = document.getElementById(DivID);
    if(div){

        const Elements = div.children //Here, I need the list;

        for (let i = 0; i < Elements.length; i++){
            if (i == 0) { continue; }
            else {Elements[i].style = "display:block";}
        }
    }
    return null;

}
</script>
```

More details about [`Element.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get rid of `first child` as:

```js
function handleImages(id) {
  const allChildren = [...document.querySelectorAll(`#${id} > img`)];
  allChildren.forEach(
    (imgChild, index) =>
    (imgChild.style.display = index === 0 ? "block" : "none")
  );
}
handleImages("RandomId");
```

```html
<div id="RandomId">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
</div>
```